# Segfault passing argument in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I'm having trouble with fortran when passing parameters to a method.

For the context, I'm trying to learn how to implement object-oriented programmation in order to maintain a program written in Fortran 90.

I've written an example which shows what I'm trying to do, and I don't really know what's the good way to code it, and my researches on the web remain vain.

```
module animal_mod

    type, abstract :: animal
        integer :: age
    contains
        procedure(speak_interface), deferred :: speak
    end type animal

    abstract interface
        subroutine speak_interface(self)
            import :: animal
            class(animal), intent(in) :: self
        end subroutine
    end interface

end module

module cat_mod

    use animal_mod

    type, extends (animal) :: cat
        character (len=8) :: fur
    contains
        procedure :: speak => speak_cat
    end type cat

contains
    subroutine speak_cat(self)
        class(cat), intent(in) :: self
        print *, "Meow"
    end subroutine
end module

program animals
    use cat_mod

    implicit none

    type(cat) :: my_cat
    my_cat%fur="Shiny"
    my_cat%age=3

    call make_it_speak(my_cat)

end program animals

subroutine make_it_speak(my_animal)
    use animal_mod
    class(animal), intent(in) :: my_animal
    call my_animal%speak()
end subroutine
```

The problem is that i declare my variable as a type(cat), and my subroutine takes a class(animal) as a parameter. However, I can't declare a type(animal) because of the abstraction.

Could you help me about this topic?

PS: I've defined an interface because it was mentioned in the tutorials and the documentations I went through, but I didn't really get its point.

Comment: What is the problem you are having?  Is there a message from the compiler, or is it giving the wrong answer?  [I note that your subroutine `make_it_speak` appears to be outside everything else - is this really the case?]

Comment: Well, to be precise, it's "conceived" in Fortran 90 but it already uses future features, such as associates and things. Indeed, I get a segmentation fault: I use ifort 15.1, and I get a severe(174) : SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred, where routine, line and source are marked as unknown, on 2 lines. And, where should I put my subroutine

Comment: If you put the subroutine `make_it_speak` into the module `animal_mod`, does it then work?

Comment: It does actually! But I still don't get why, and there's still this interface I don't understand ^^. Couldn't I then factorise my code? Because in my animal module, I now have make_it_speak and speak_interface

Comment: Do you mean `speak_interface` and `speak_cat`?  `speak_interface` and `make_it_speak` are not related at all.

Comment: Hum, what I meant is that, in my real program, it can happen that one instance of an animal is given as a parameter of a function in a completely different module. I'd just like to be able to do an animal%speak() in that module, and I don't know how

Comment: I tried your program on my machine and it ran perfectly fine as long as make_it_speak() is contained in some module (located below animal_mod in the module hierarchy). So I think no problem...

Comment: _However, I can't declare a type(animal) because of the abstraction._ Isn't it the desired result? I.e., we generate something that belongs to "animal" (like cat or dog or sunflower) but we don't want to generate "animal" (which is an abstract concept). So we make a sunflower and pass it to a routine that receives any "animal" (ooo, sunflower is not animal... replace it with cat etc)

Answer (score 1):

You have two questions: about the segmentation fault and about the interface.

To answer about the segmentation fault, the subroutine `make_it_speak` has a polymorphic argument `my_animal`.  It is polymorphic because it is declared as `class(animal)`.  This requires that the main program - which calls this subroutine - must have an explicit interface available to it.  Placing the subroutine into `animal_mod` does that through use association.  You can find much discussion in other questions and answers.

Coming to the abstract interface in `animal_mod`, let's look at that module in isolation.

When declaring the deferred type-bound procedure `speak` of the abstract type `animal` its interface must be specified.  Again, this interface must be an explicit interface for the type.  The interface block is one way to provide this explicit interface.  Another would be to have a procedure, perhaps called `speak_animal`.  With this latter, though, you're no longer really deferring.

Why can't you use `speak_cat`, being one suitable implementation, as the interface rather than repeat yourself with `speak_interface`?  One major reason is that inside the module `animal_mod` `speak_cat` isn't visible.  It isn't possible to make it available through use association as there would then be a cyclic dependency.

How about merging `animal_mod` and `cat_mod` to get this visibility?  That won't work either: the passed argument of `speak_cat` is of `class(cat)` rather than the required `class(animal)`.  You need this to ensure that your `class(dog)`s are happy.

So, your abstract interface block is the way to go.